# Where clause not entering lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following lambda

```
var entities = JTransformer.Queryer.GetList()
  .Where(x => { var y = JStubs.GetType(x.Name); 
    return (y.Impliments(baseType) && y.IsGenericType); });
```

I've set a break point in the JStub.GetType function I created, but it fails to hit it every time I try to run the statement.

`JTransformer.Queryer.GetList()` is returning an Enumerable, and I've checked to make sure that it has values

```
-       Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable   
+       [0] {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity} JsonMap.Interfaces.IEntity {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity}
+       [1] {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity} JsonMap.Interfaces.IEntity {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity}
+       [2] {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity} JsonMap.Interfaces.IEntity {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity}
+       [3] {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity} JsonMap.Interfaces.IEntity {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity}
+       [4] {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity} JsonMap.Interfaces.IEntity {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity}
+       [5] {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity} JsonMap.Interfaces.IEntity {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity}
+       [6] {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity} JsonMap.Interfaces.IEntity {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity}
+       [7] {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity} JsonMap.Interfaces.IEntity {JsonMap.Default.Types.JEntity}
```

So why is my lambda never being run?

Edit:

I should clarify. I am later doing a `for-each` on entities, and it had nothing to iterate over.

```
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    (some code never get's hit)
}
```

but when I do the following

```
var entities = JTransformer.Queryer.GetList().ToList()
    .Where(x => { var y = JStubs.GetType(x.Name); 
        return (y.Impliments(baseType) && y.IsGenericType); });
```

all of a sudden entities has values in it and the code in the `for-each` get's hit

Comment: Try by appending a `.ToList()` to it.

Comment: It won't hit breakpoint when you execute the line you gave. It's only constructing a query, it's **not** iterating over it. Try to add `ToList()` at the end and rerun in debug mode

Comment: You're creating a query, which you don't use. Therefore it is never iterated over, and `GetType` is not going to be called. To execute the query, you can call `ToList()` on it which will execute the query and give you the results as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, entities is *not* a collection. It's a deferred call that returns a collection.

There's a slight semantic difference there, which is more obvious when you consider using yielding infinitely sized IEnumerables. Eg.

```
public IEnumerable<int> InfiniteRepeat(int i)
{
    do
    {
        yield return i;
    } while (true);
}
```

As you can see, you could never actually *store* that collection. If you were to call InfiniteRepeat(1).ToList() you'd throw an OutOfMemoryException.

Your case appears to be similar. You have some kind of query, that gets executed when you try to inspect the values in debug mode, but at runtime, there is nothing. Calling ToList() forces the IEnumerable to load the contents into memory (the list), which forces evaluation of the IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` or iterate within a `for-each` that causes the 'actual' execution of the enumeration. By itself, it will do nothing except create a `Func` reference.